# How To Load Balancing on Bind9 Dns Server?

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing, bind, ubuntu-14.04, round-robin

i have a DNS server running on ubuntu 14.04 - bind9 , because the server is hosted on t2 micro amazon free tier i don't think it can handle all requests that it will get , over 10000+ clients will use my DNS server ..

so i was thinking of some sort of Load-Balancing like running another instance and setup a round-robin or something on the main DNS to load-balance requests between him and the second instance ..

how to do that ?! ( i guess you get the idea of what i want to do any solution will work )

Answer (score 2):

Prerequisite: Configure the secondary DNS as slave of your primary DNS.

Then configure your clients to load balance the requests to both the DNS server, using for instance the option "rotate" in /etc/resolv.conf (example: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/improving_dns_lookups.htm )